# init coder of UIView reload after call instantiateWithOwner

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I make custom `uiview` in swift and this is the code

```
@IBDesignable public class HomeScreenCodeView: UIView {


    var view :UIView!



    var nibName : String = "HomeScreenView"



    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // 1. setup any properties here

        // 2. call super.init(coder:)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()


        view.frame = bounds


        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight


        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName , bundle: bundle)

        // Assumes UIView is top level and only object in CustomView.xib file
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
        return view
    }
```

The problem is when called  `let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView`

the `init coder` recall and the `xibSetup()` recall too , This  cause Infinite loop    .
How to solve this problem and stop init from reloading.
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instantitateWithOwner` loads a nib/xib file which in turn calls `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. (source: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW6))

That's why you got that infinite loop. You can remove XibSetup from your init methods to stop the loop.

Comment: yes I explain that the instantitateWithOwner reload coder init

Comment: Well that doesn't explain why you willfully created this loop then

Comment: Thanks for your help , but is there any solution to keep xibSetup() in init coder

Comment: yes, you can wrap your XibSetup() in a conditionnal that checks if the view has already been loaded so the loop is executed only once (you can use a boolean with a default false value that is set to true the first time loadViewFromNib is executed. Then XibSetup() has to be executed only if this boolean is false

Comment: Nice explain , Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid the infinite loop, you have to go in your XIB from your `CustomView` and associate the File Owner to your `customView` swift Class.

Carefull, the class of you xib (the "View" in the storyboard Hierarchy) has to be `UIView` and not `CustomView`.

The wrap with a boolean can not work if you do not do this because you create a new instance at each loop. 
Cheers